# Google Cloud Run - Cloudinary Integration for File Upload

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, cloudinary

I have a node.js service running in google cloud using Cloud Run provided by them. Where I am using Cloudinary for File upload. It was working fine until recently but now it has stopped working.
The code seems to work fine on local and Render (Cloud Service).

I was using express.js and multer for file upload. I have isolated the code and tested a code where I have only one API for file upload and using normal request without multer just cloudinary sdk but it is still not working.

Please Tell me how can I solve this.

**Code**

```
const express = require('express');
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary').v2;
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();
// Configure Cloudinary
cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
  api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
  api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_SECRET
});

// Create Express app
const app = express();

// Enable JSON parsing middleware
app.use(express.json());

// POST route for uploading a PNG file to Cloudinary
app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
  // Check if a file was uploaded
  if (!req.body || !req.body.data) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'No file uploaded' });
  }

  // Upload file to Cloudinary
  cloudinary.uploader.upload(
    req.body.data,
    { resource_type: 'image', format: 'png' },
    (error, result) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error('Upload error:', error);
        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to upload file' });
      }
     
      // Return the Cloudinary URL of the uploaded image
      res.json({ url: result.secure_url });
    }
  );
});

// Start the server
app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log('Server started on port 3000');
});
```

**Request**

```
curl --location 'https://fileuploadwithoutmulter-ssnwhxubxq-em.a.run.app/upload' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
    "data":"data:image/jpg;base64,<BASE64_CODE>" }'
```

**Logs - Cloud Run(Google Cloud Platform)**

```
2023-05-19 02:06:43.937 IST
POST500760 B2 sPostmanRuntime/7.32.2 https://fileuploadwithoutmulter-ssnwhxubxq-em.a.run.app/upload
2023-05-19 02:06:45.966 IST
Upload error: Error [ERR_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT]: Socket connection timeout
2023-05-19 02:06:45.966 IST
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
2023-05-19 02:06:45.966 IST
at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1099:20)
2023-05-19 02:06:45.966 IST
at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1638:3)
2023-05-19 02:06:45.966 IST
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
2023-05-19 02:06:45.966 IST
at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
2023-05-19 02:06:45.966 IST
code: 'ERR_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT'
2023-05-19 02:06:45.966 IST
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "fileuploadwithoutmulter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cloudinary": "^1.37.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  }
}
```

Cloudinary SDK Version: 1.37.0
Approx Request Time: 2:05 IST

Comment: Could you try to test your `'/upload'` endpoint without the `cloudinary.uploader.upload(..)`? Looking at your code, it seems that accessing your endpoint is being blocked in your cloud platform environment. Also, in case your endpoint is not blocked and to capture the unhandled error within your API, you could also consider using try-catch and log the exception for better understanding of the case.

Comment: I did that it seems to work fine without cloudinary uploader as I uploaded it using "fs" module. Even when I used try catch the error that comes in is same.

Comment: did you resolve this error?

Comment: no i was not able to solve it.